# shell script grep only working on last line of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a very strange problem I've never encountered and could not find anything related on other posts here, I have a shell script that just greps a test host file(will use real one once this works) in a while loop but it will only output the last line:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    grep $line /etc/test/hosts
done < temp-file.txt
```

here is the /etc/test/hosts file:

> device1  192.168.0.1
>   device2  192.168.0.2
>   device3  192.168.0.3
>   // cut
>   device50 192.168.0.50

the temp-file.txt is identical to the test host file for testing

And as mentioned, here is the output - only showing last line:
device3  192.168.0.50

If I change the `grep` command to just `echo $line` it outputs correctly. I have tried changing the number of lines in the test host file to be more and less but same result. I have also done the `grep` command from cli and it works fine on every device I `grep` for. I have also tried putting the $line in double quotes but that also has not changed anything.

I have also tried an alternate while loop using the `while IFS="\n"` method but same results. This seems like it should be extraordinarily simple but I'm having issues. Am I doing something wrong or is this maybe a bug in bash?

Comment: Does your `/etc/test/hosts` file perhaps have `\r` in it which could make the output overwrite itself on each iteration?  Also, if you have spaces in `$line` you'd need to quote it when using it with `grep`

Comment: i added the following at the top and it looks like it got it:
sed -i 's/\r$//' temp-file.txt

thanks for the fast reply

Comment: You might also consider `grep -f`, which would let you search with all the patterns in temp-file.txt at once. See the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

question answered by Eric Renouf via comment.

solution:

add sed `-i 's/\r$//'` temp-file.txt to top of script to remove the \r that were at the end of each line.